# How can I delete a datafile that has no tablespace without accessing the filesystem?

Tags: oracle

I dropped a tablespace and accidentally did not drop the data file with it. Now I cannot find the data file in dba_data_files. I don't have access to the filesystem to delete the files directly. How can I remove it using oracle commands?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Create a new tablespace
2. Add the datafile to the tablespace
3. Drop the tablespace and its datafiles

For example:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE MYAPP
DATAFILE '/mnt/data/app/oracle/oradata/MYAPP_02.dat'
SIZE 100M AUTOEXTEND ON;

alter tablespace MYAPP add datafile '/mnt/data/app/oracle/oradata/MYAPP_01.dat';

drop tablespace MYAPP including contents and datafiles;
```

Comment: Hmm. Looks like you posted your own answer to your own question.  What prevented you from simply doing an 'rm /mnt/data/app/oracle/oradata/MYAPP_01.dat'?

Comment: I have the password for the SYS user, but I do not have one for an OS user. That's my question says 'without accessing the filesystem'. I didn't find this approach as quickly as I would have liked so I posted this question and the answer for others to take advantage.

Comment: That's exactly what stackoverflow is for. Thank you, helped me a lot.